# How to format date with DateFormatter that includes friendly day and month

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

How can I format a date that includes a friendly day and month literal such as:

> "Thursday, June 14, 2018"

Day can be:

> Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wedenesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday,
>   Friday

Month can be:

> January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September,
>   October, November, December

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = format
return formatter.date(from: "Thursday, June 14, 2018")
```

What should the format be set to?

Something like this?

```
static let format = "DAY, MONTH, dd, YYYY"
```

Is it even possible to do this with DateFormatter() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EEEE` for the full weekday name and `MMMM` for the full month name. But since you are parsing fixed formatted strings that are in English, you must also set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
return formatter.date(from: "Thursday, June 14, 2018")
```

Note that this will treat the date as being in the user's local timezone.

See the [full specification](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for all possible date formatting patterns.